# Compute the derivative from the definition of $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\neq 0.$ Is $f'(x)$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Compute the derivative from the definition of $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\neq 0.$ Is $f'(x)$ continuous?

I tried using the definition of continuity and I wasn't sure how to show formally that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x).$ Obviously, the derivative is $\dfrac{2}{x^3}e^{-1/x^2}.$

Here's my attempt.
So by the definition of the derivative, the derivative of $f(x)$ at a point $x$ is

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{e^{-1/(x+h)^2}-e^{-1/x^2}}{h}=e^{-1/x^2}\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{e^{-1/(x+h)^2+1/x^2}-1}{h}\\
=e^{-1/x^2}\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{e^{(2h+h^2)/(x^2(x+h)^2)}-1}{h},$$ but here I'm stuck. How can I get to the desired limit? Any help would be appreciated.

I know that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{e^h-1}{h}=1.$ Also, we want to show that $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{e^{(2hx+h^2)/(x^2(x+h)^2)}-1}{h}=\dfrac{2}{x^3}$$

I was thinking of using the Taylor series expansion for $e^x,$ but isn't there some other way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Taylor expansion approach should work. If you want to use the full series, then you need to mention the uniform convergence of the series. If you truncate and use some low order approximation, you don't need to do that. Also, are you sure you need to find $f'(x)$ for $x\neq 0$ by definition? The interesting case is $x=0$, since this function gives an example of an infinitely differentiable function which is not analytic at the origin.

Comment: Note that $$  \frac 1 {x^2} - \frac 1 {(x+h)^2} = \frac {h (2x + h)}{x^2 (x+h)^2} \xrightarrow {h \to 0} 0 \cdot \frac {2x}{x^4} =0,$$ and apply the limit you have learned: $(\mathrm e^h - 1)/h \to 1 [h \to 0]$.

Comment: @Reveillark yes I'm sure I want to find the derivative at $x\neq 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay you can use something similar to chain rule by this

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{ e^{-1/(x+h)^2 } - e^{-1/x^2}}{h} $$ Then Multiply by $$\frac{-1/(x+h)^2 - -1/x^2}{-1/(x+h)^2 - -1/x^2}$$

To get 
$$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{ e^{-1/(x+h)^2 } - e^{-1/x^2}}{-1/(x+h)^2 - (-1/x^2)} \frac{ -1/(x+h)^2 - (-1/x^2)}{h} $$

Now we can distribute the limit

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{ e^{-1/(x+h)^2 } - e^{-1/x^2}}{-1/(x+h)^2 - (-1/x^2)} \lim_{h\rightarrow 0 } \frac{ -1/(x+h)^2 - (-1/x^2)}{h}$$

Now we need to solve the first limit let $u = -1/(x+h)^2+1/x^2  $ then $u \rightarrow 0 $ as $h \rightarrow 0$ Hence

$$\lim_{u \rightarrow 0 } \frac{ e^{u- 1/x^2} - e^{-1/x^2}}{u } = \lim_{u \rightarrow 0 }  \frac{e^{-1/x^2}(e^u-1)}{u} = e^{-1/x^2}$$
For the second limit 
$$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0 } \frac{ -1/(x+h)^2 - (-1/x^2)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{ -x^2 + ( x^2 + 2xh + h^2)}{h(x+h)^2x^2}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{2x + h}{(x+h)^2 x^2 } = \frac{2}{x^3}$$

The answer is the product of the two limits i.e. $e^{-1/x^2} \frac{2}{x^3}$ which is the derivative of $f(x)$ right?? .

So in general if you have a composition of functions and you need to find the derivative using the definition say something like this 
$$\lim \frac{f(g(x+h)) - f(g(x))}{h} = \lim \frac{f(g(x+h)) - f(g(x))}{g(x+h) - g(x)} \frac{g(x+h) - g(x) }{h} $$
Then for the first limit we use a substitution $u = g(x+h) -g(x)$ then as $h$ goes to zero then $u$ goes to $0$ then

$$\lim \frac{f(u + g(x)) - f(g(x))}{u} $$ this is similar to $\lim \frac{f(u+r) - f(r)}{u}$ So in above you can make one substitution.

Comment: Are you sure your first equality is valid?

Comment: OH yeah you caught me thanks I will fix it

Comment: @AmerYR you just showed that $f'(x)=\lim\limits_{u\to -1/x^2}\dfrac{e^{-1/x^2}(e^u-1)}{u}.$ I don't get how that's computing the derivative.

Comment: @user63710 I edited my answer

Comment: @user63710 thanks for the answer. It was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$  \frac 1 {x^2} - \frac 1 {(x+h)^2} = \frac {h (2x + h)}{x^2 (x+h)^2} \xrightarrow {h \to 0} 0 \cdot \frac {2x}{x^4} =0,$$ so the difference of the two fractions is an infinitesimal. Now apply the limit you have learned: $$\frac {\mathrm e^h - 1}h \to 1 [h \to 0],$$
by substituting the infinitesimals to a simpler one according this limit expression.

Comment: how does this show that the derivative is continuous? I honestly prefer using the Taylor series.

Comment: I did not write anything about the continuity of $f'$.

Comment: how am I supposed to show that it is continuous whenever $x\neq 0$? any hints would be nice